# Retry Failed Automation Test Case from the logical point for E2E Automation

Tags: testing, automation, spock, geb, recovery

We are trying to automate E2E test cases for an booking application which involves around 60+ steps for each test case. Whenever there is a failure at the final steps it is very much time consuming if we go for traditional retry option since the test case will be executed from step 1 again. On the application we have some logical steps which can be marked somehow through which we would like to achieve resuming the test case from a logical point before the failed step. Say for example, among the 60 steps say every 10th step is a logical point in which the script can be resumed instead of retrying from the step 1. say if the failure is on line number 43 then with the help of booking reference number the test can be resumed from step number 41 since the validation has been completed till step 40 (step 40 is a logical closure point). There might be an option you may suggest to split the test case into smaller modules, which will not work for me since it is an E2E test case for the application which we would want to have in a single Geb Spec. The framework is built using Geb & Spock for Web Application automation. Please share your thoughts / logics on how can we build the recovery scenarios for this case. Thanks for your support.!

As of now i am not able to find out any solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: Don't do this! First, fix your flaky integration test.Or maybe the failure really exposes some subtle defect or race condition in your application. Don't take flaky tests lightly. Repetition hides the root cause and only covers up the symptom. Also, as you said, such an integration test is slow, so you want to avoid repetition. Second, make your application more testable by providing a means to start an integration test at any important customer journey step. Then you can decompose your big test into smaller ones. **Solve the problem,** don't look for workarounds!

Answer (score 0):

Below are few things which can be done to achieve the same, but before we talk about the solutions, we should also talk about the issues which it will create. You are running E2E test cases and if they fail at step 10 then they should be started from scratch not from step 10 because you can miss important integration defects which are occurring when you perform 10th step after running first 9 steps. For e.g. if you create an account and then immediately search for hotel, you application might through error because its a newly created account, but if you retry it from a step where you are just trying to search for the hotel rooms then it might work, because of the time spent between your test failure and restarting the test, and you will not notice this issue.

Now if you must achieve this then

Create a log every time you reach a checkpoint, which can be a simple text file indicating the test case name and checkpoint number, then use retry analyzer for running the failed tests, inside the test look for the text file with the test case name, if it exists then simple skip the code to the checkpoint mentioned in the text file. It can be used in different ways, for e.g. if your e2e test if going through 3 applications then file can have the test case name and the last passed application name, if you have used page objects then you can write the last successful page object name in the text file and use that for continuing the test.

Above solution is just an idea, because I dont think there are any existing solutions for this issue.

Hope this will give you an idea about how to start working on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your end to end test case is too big and too brittle.  What's the reasoning behind needing it all in one script.

You've already stated you can use the booking reference to continue on at a later step if it fails, this seems like a logical place to split your tests.

Do the first bit, output the booking reference to a file.  Read the booking reference for the second test and complete the journey, if it fails then a retry won't take anywhere near as long.

If you're using your tests to provide quick feedback after a build and your tests keep failing then I would look to split up the journey into smaller smoke tests, and if required run some overnight end to end tests with as many retries as you like.

The fact it keeps failing suggests your tests, environment or build is brittle.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution to your problem is to first define the way in which you want to write your tests.
I would recommend considering one test Spec (class) as one E2E test containing multiple features.
Also, it is recommended to use opensource [Spock Retry](https://github.com/anotherchrisberry/spock-retry) project available on GitHub, after implementing RetryOnFailure

your final code should look like:

```
@RetryOnFailure(times= 2) // times parameter is for retry attempts, default= 0
class MyEndtoEndTest1 extends GebReportingSpec {
def bookingRefNumber

def "First Feature block which cover the Test till a logical step"()
{
// your test steps here
bookingRefNumber = //assign your booking Ref here
}

def "Second Feature which covers a set of subsequent logical steps "()
{
//use the bookingRefNumber generated in the First Feature block
}

def "Third set of Logical Steps"()
{ // your test steps here
}

def "End of the E2E test "()
{ // Your final Test steps here
}
```

The passing of all the Feature blocks (methods) will signify a successful E2E test execution.